# How can I import .Rnw files in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, rstudio

I am working on a project in R Studio, through R I create .Rnw files for editing in LaTeX. Now I want to find a way or create a command that allow me to insert a .rnw file from another .rnw file. For example, if I think the Example.Rnw file, I can read it from anywhere in my main file main.Rnw. Help me please!.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/haziqj/latex-article-template) help ?